# how does Express or Connect generate routes?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

to add a route in express I run:

```
app.get('/users', handler);
```

as a result, i have a new route object in `app.routes.get`:

```
{ path: '/admin/users',
  method: 'get',
  callbacks: [ [Function] ],
  keys: [],
  regexp: /^\/admin\/users\/?$/i }
```

I have looked through the source code of the Express and the Connect library and can't figure out where this operation is defined.

For me it's enough to know the algorithm used to generate the regexp.

Thank you

Comment: I would start looking here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/route.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably found it by now, but from what I can tell, the regexp is generated in `express/lib/utils.js:exports.pathRegexp()`